# ListView OnScrollListener doesn't get called inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, onscroll

I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` which creates it's child pages (which are `ListFragments`) as follows:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return FragmentChildPage.newInstance();
}
```

I give the ViewPager an `OffscreenPageLimit` of 1. The child `ListFragments` have a custom `ScrollListener`.

The issue I have is the custom scroll listener only works on child `ListFragments` that are created when the ViewPager is swiped past its `OffscreenPageLimit`, i.e. child pages > 2.

More confusing is if I scroll several pages and then return to the first page the scroll listener now works.

What is going on here? It seems the `ViewPager` interferes with some of the child pages `OnScrollListener`.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out. Works for me!

```
public class ActivityTest extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private TestAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(android.R.id.button1);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        mAdapter = new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class TestAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TestAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return TestListFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }

    }

    private static class TestListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

        private static final String TAG = TestListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        private String[] mItems = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

        private int mPos;

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public static TestListFragment newInstance(int pos) {
            TestListFragment frag = new TestListFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("pos", pos);
            frag.setArguments(b);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mPos = getArguments().getInt("pos");
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mItems));

            getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {              
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScroll() - Fragment: " + mPos);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This example works fine for me and doesn't look to dissimilar to my implementation. I'll therefore have to go through and remove parts of code until I find out what's breaking it. Thanks.

Comment: @Milo Did you ever find what exactly the problem was?